# WordPress pages and posts are redirecting to server IP address instead of domain URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

I have set the site URL and WordPress URL as the domain name only.
I haven't statically used the site's IP address in wp-admin area. I have used the permalink `domain name/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`.

When I click on any page or post, a 404 error is displayed. The domain name is replaced with IP address.
The .htaccess file having the basic content.When I click on any page or post it redirecting to the root folder IP as XXX.XXX.X.73/index.php/page.
This is working on IP:Port number.At the time of redirecting it showing only the IP.I need to run it with domain name.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move WordPress site from one domain to another](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57772/move-wordpress-site-from-one-domain-to-another)

Comment: I have followed the instructions.The issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

What about using this -
`domain name/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Comment: Yes.I have provided the writable permission for  .htaccess file. I have used custom permalink structure as "domain name/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/"

Comment: I see there is an `index.php` in the permalink structure. Check with and without it.

Comment: If I removed the index.php from the permalink it showing the error like this
"If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all."

Comment: you need to set proper permission for .htaccess file.